# unit test How to do a unit test for create method

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I want to write a unit test below method.

Using this method I can add a user and this is works fine.  user can be saved.

```
public async Task<UserModel> SaveAsync(UserModel model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ExternalUserId))
    {
        var extUser = await identityManagementService.CreateUser(model);

        user = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            ExternalUserId = extUser.UserId,
            IsActive = true,
            UserName = model.Email,
        };
        user.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        var exists = false;
        
        await applicationUserRepository.AddOrUpdateAsync(user, a => exists);
    }
    await applicationUserRepository.SaveAsync();

                var IsSaved = await identityManagementService.GetUserById(user.ExternalUserId); // to check the user is saved


    return model;

}
```

unit test

```
 [Fact]
        public async Task SaveAsync_Should_AddORUpdate_WhenExternalUserIdDoesNOtExsitsAndProfileImgIsNull() // userRole is exist
        {
            var userModel = UserMockData.UserCorrectModelWithExternalUsserIdEmpty();
            var applicationRole = UserMockData.ApplicationRole();

            _identityManagementService.Setup(x => x.CreateUser(userModel)).Returns(Task.FromResult(UserMockData.User()));
            // _identityManagementService.Setup(x => x.GetUserById(userModel.ExternalUserId)).Returns(() => null);

            _applicationRoleRepository.Setup(x => x.FindAsync(userModel.RoleId)).Returns(Task.FromResult(applicationRole));
            _identityManagementService.Setup(x => x.AssignUserRoles(It.Is<String>(g => g != String.Empty), applicationRole.ExternalRoleId)).Returns(Task.FromResult(true));
            var sut = new UserManagementService(
                _applicationRoleRepository.Object,
                _applicationUserRepository.Object,
                _applicationRolePermissionRepository.Object,
                _identityManagementService.Object,
                _smtpEmailService.Object,
            _logger.Object
                );

            // Act
            var result = await sut.SaveAsync(userModel);

            //Asset
            result.Should().NotBeNull();

            var x = _identityManagementService.Object.GetUserById(userModel.ExternalUserId).Result; // this is null
            var y = _applicationRoleRepository.Object.ListAsync(false).Result?.Count(); //  this is also null

            x.Should().Be(1);


        }
```

When I check the method in debugging mode
`var IsSaved = await identityManagementService.GetUserById(user.ExternalUserId); // to check the user is saved` this line is not null.

But when I checked unit test debug mode,
`var IsSaved = await identityManagementService.GetUserById(user.ExternalUserId); // to check the user is saved` is null

How can I verify/test the user is saved by this method?

Please guide me.

Comment: In your test method, you are creating `userModel` by calling `UserMockData.UserCorrectModelWithExternalUsserIdEmpty()`. I cannot see that you populate `userModel.ExternalUserId` before calling `_identityManagementService.Object.GetUserById()`. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have not mock the GetUserById method. You have to mock the GetUserById method. In mock we are not doing actual creation that's why your GetUserById is giving result as null.

Please add below code in your test method -

```
  _identityManagementService.Setup(x => x.GetUserById(userModel.ExternalUserId)).Returns(true);
```

Comment: Okay, by mocking I can set GetUserById return an expected result.  But I can I test the new model is saved or not?

Comment: You can't verify your new model is saved or not with mock. I think you expected to save your model in DB and then you will get user by I'd. This not possible with mock. If you want to do this then you have to add integration test.